# Does $y_1<y_2/2 \implies f^{-1}(y_1)<\frac{1}{2}f^{-1}(y_2)$ for $f$ an increasing concave function with nonzero domain?

Tags: functions, solution-verification, convex-analysis

Suppose $f:X\to Y$ is an increasing, concave function, (**edit: Domain $X$ is non-zero numbers. no negative numbers**)

Consider $y_1<0.5y_2$, $y_1,y_2 \in Y$ ($y_1, y_2$ are in the range of $f$)

**Must it be that $f^{-1}(y_1)<0.5f^{-1}(y_2)$ where $f^{-1}$ denotes the inverse function)?**

I think the answer is yes, with the proof sketch below

- Maybe its not true if $f(0)\not= 0$, but I think its fine there too

Edit: I meant to include in statement to assume the domain of $f$ is only nonzero numbers, but forgot to... some answers have pointed out that when the domain can be negative the statement is not true. Sorry for the error

---

I think the answer is yes, following this Proof sketch:

Consider the line from $f(0)=0$ to $f(y_2)$. Let the (linear) function for this line be denoted $g(x)$, which is WLOG $a+bx$ for some $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$,$b>0$

Consider $\frac{g^{-1}(y_1)}{g^{-1}(y_2)}$

$$\frac{g^{-1}(y_1)}{g^{-1}(y_2)}= \frac{(y_1-a)/b}{(y_2-a)/b}=\frac{y_1-a}{y_2-a} \tag{1}$$

Consider if $a=0$ then eq (1) is $<.5$.

Then use the fact that by concavity $f(x)$ is to the left of $g(x)$ on $[y_1,y_2)$, which means $f^{-1}(y_1)<g^{-1}(y_1)$.

If $a\not = 0$ then I think it still holds since $\frac{y_1-a}{y_2-a}<\frac{y_1}{y_2}$ for $y_1,y_2>a$, the latter condition of which is true by definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $y_2\geq 0$ then $y_1 < \frac12y_2$ implies $y_1<y_2$ and since $f$ is increasing, so is $f^{-1}$, as a result $f^{-1}(y_1) < f^{-1}(y_2)$ purely due to the monotonicity.

If $y_2 < 0$ then it is not true. Since $y_1 = \frac 12y_2$ satisfies your condition, but  for negative numbers you get $\frac 12 y_2 > y_2$ and hence $f^{-1}(y_1) > f^{-1}(y_2)$.

Concavity was never used, only monotonicity.

---

For the updated question: the function $f^{-1}$ is convex, hence in particular
$$
f^{-1}(\frac12a + \frac12b) \leq \frac12 (f^{-1}(a) + f^{-1}(b))
$$
for all $a,b\geq 0$. If you take $a = 0$ and $b = y_2$ you get
$$
f^{-1}(y_1) \leq f^{-1}\left(\frac12 y_2\right) \leq \frac12 f^{-1}(0) + \frac12f^{-1}(y_2)
$$
where the first inequality holds thanks to monotonicity, and second due to convexity of $f^{-1}$. This inequality is also tight, meaning that one can construct the case of equality (take a linear function, for example). For this reason, unless you have some assumption on $f^{-1}(0)$, in general your claim does not hold true.

Comment: yes, but To show (with $y_1,y_2>0$) that $f^{-1}(y_1)<\frac{1}{2}f^{-1}(y_2)$ needs more than just monotocity though, (assuming it is true for positive $y_1,y_2$

Comment: @user106860 please, fix the title then

Comment: @user106860 I meant that the title is missing the $\frac12$ part

Comment: This is a very nice answer. And it is clear that with $f^{-1}(0)>0$ this need not be true, and with $f^{-1}(0)=0$ it is true, and it looks like with $f^{-1}(0)<0$ it is also true (although that would require considering functions with negative domains)